# Displaying a png-file on a display - stays black

Tags: mobile-robot, webots

In Webots with a Python controller: I have a PNG-File (640x480) which displays a Matrix-Numpy-Array-figure which is getting produced by my code. I would like to display it on an Display overlay. But display.imageLoad(filename.png) produces no visable image on the Display. It seems to load it, because if i remove the ".png" than it produces an error. What can I change to see it?

Hier is my world file:
https://github.com/MaximilianKlein92/Webots-Breitenberg/commit/25f6645ee3c4184fe4b46559735472f17f07ec24

Here my Controller:
https://github.com/MaximilianKlein92/Webots-Breitenberg/commit/59ceafb0833c29ffbb7e7b7562b0fba4dae587be

And here a short Video:
https://webots.cloud/AcRB4U4?upload=webots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Display.imageLoad` simply reads the image from file and store it internally in Webots. To actually show the image in the Display, you have to call `Display.imagePaste` that will copy the image data into the Display board.

I saw in your code that you tried to call `Display.imagePaste` but the arguments are wrong:

- the first expected argument is the image reference returned by `Display.imageLoad` (and not the image file name)
- the second (`x`) and third (`y`) arguments specify the top left position of the copied image in the Display board:
  so if you set `x=imageWidth, y=imageHeight`, the figure won't be visible in the Display board

So the correct code will be something like:

```
figure_ref = display.imageLoad(filename+".jpeg")
display.imagePaste(figure_ref, 0, 0, False)
```

For reference, [here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/display?tab-language=python#wb_display_image_load) is the link to the complete Display API documentation.

Just note that you should also change the line 305 where the figure is saved and specify the extension by adding `+'.jpeg'`:

```
plt.savefig(filename + '.jpeg',format="jpeg")
```

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*

Comment: Thank you very much! this was the problem! Greate Answer :)